# Confused by class constructor and initializer list, suspicious of circular dependency

Tags: c++, constructor, circular-dependency, forward-declaration, initializer-list

I want to pass a referenced instance of a class through another class's constructor. Now I cannot do so, because I get stuck in syntax error. I tried for several hours, though I learned many things (such as circular dependency or forward declaration), but practically cannot solve my issue. I have this files:

**Project.h** (the constructor of Project class is passed a reference instance of Buffer class)

**Project.cpp**

**Buffer.h**

**Buffer.cpp**

The above four files are active in my problem (my guess).

Here is Project.h content:

```
#include<string>
#include<regex>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include "Buffer.h"

using namespace boost::filesystem;

#ifndef PROJECT_H
#define PROJECT_H

class Project(Buffer & buffer_param) : bufferObj(buffer_param)
{

    Buffer& bufferObj;

public: 
    Filer& filer;

    std::string project_directory;
    void createList(std::vector<std::string> list_title);
};

#endif
```

Here is project.cpp Content:

```
#include<string>
#include<regex>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<boost\filesystem.hpp>

#include "Project.h"


using namespace boost::filesystem;


void Project::createList(std::vector<std::string> list_title)
{
    //this->filer.createFile();
}
```

Buffer.h

```
    #include<string>
    #include<map>


    #ifndef BUFFER_H
    #define BUFFER_H

    class Buffer
    {
        std::map<std::string, std::string> storage_str;

        void setValueString(std::string key, std::string value);
        std::string getValueString(std::string key);
    };

    #endif
```

Buffer.cpp

```
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include "Buffer.h"


void Buffer::setValueString(std::string key, std::string value)
{
    this->storage_str[key] = value;
}
```

PROBLEM:

Without passing the buffer to the project constructor, everything works perfectly, but as soon as I start passing an instance of it, the errors get thrown:

All Errors of `Project.h` File:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '&'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'
error C2079: 'Buffer' uses undefined class 'Project'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2530: 'buffer_param' : references must be initialized
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ':'
error C2448: 'bufferObj' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
```

Error of `Project.cpp` File:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'Project' 
     see declaration of 'Project'
```

Comment: `class Project(Buffer & buffer_param)` !? A constructor (with or without init. list) isn´t the same as the whole class

Comment: what's the problem? Yes (I updated the question, had to typo in the file for project class)

Comment: As I just added, you´re confusing/mixing constructors with whole classes. A constructor is a single class method, similar to createList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on deviantfan's comment, instead of this

```
class Project(Buffer & buffer_param) : bufferObj(buffer_param)
{
  ...
```

There should be this:

```
class Project
{
public:
  Project(Buffer & buffer_param) : bufferObj(buffer_param)
  {
  }

private:
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks. It did work. But a side question, with this type of header declaration, then I cannot have `Project::Project() {..}` in my `Project.cpp`, Yes? Because it throws an error that `Project::Project()` has already a body. It seems I should do all of constructor's staff in the header file?

Comment: @MostafaTalebi You can (and should) put the content of your constructor in the cpp file. But if you do, it can´t be in the header file at the same time. Only one of the two files.